# AWS Amplify & React Native - Unable to resolve "@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm attempting to customize the AWS Amplify UI signin/signup process by following [this article](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication#customize-withauthenticator). Every time I import anything from `aws-amplify-react` I receive this error:

```
Unable to resolve "@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css" from "node_modules/aws-amplify-react/dist/Amplify-UI/Amplify-UI-Components-React.js"
```

I've tried installing `@aws-amplify/ui` specifically, along with other combinations of `aws-amplify` versions. Here's the relevant part of my `package.json`:

```
...
"aws-amplify": "^1.1.25",
"aws-amplify-react": "^2.3.5",
"aws-amplify-react-native": "^2.1.9",
...
```

And the versions of the specific UI & auth that I've tried:

```
"@aws-amplify/auth": "^1.2.21",
"@aws-amplify/ui": "^1.0.2",
```

Here is the import statement:

```
import { ConfirmSignIn, ConfirmSignUp, ForgotPassword, RequireNewPassword, SignIn, SignUp, VerifyContact, withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';
```

Any help on resolving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your import statement look like?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the import statement: `import { ConfirmSignIn, ConfirmSignUp, ForgotPassword, RequireNewPassword, SignIn, SignUp, VerifyContact, withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just ran into this issue as well today.

The issue was using `aws-amplify-react` instead of `aws-amplify-react-native`.
So go ahead and npm uninstall the react version, and npm install the react-native version.

The subtly mentioned this with a comment in that doc you linked:

> `import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react'; // or 'aws-amplify-react-native';`